# Possible circular import in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have this structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
├── sources
│   └── passport
│       ├── field_mapping.
│       ├── listener.py
│       ├── main.py
```

this is my init file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import views
```

my views file. Is this the best way to send plain text?

```
from app import app
from flask import Response
from sources.app_metrics import meters

# from sources.passport.main import subscription_types

@app.route('/metrics')
def metrics():
    def generateMetrics():
        metrics = ""
        for subscription in ["something", "some other thing"]:
            metrics += "thing_{}_count {}\n".format(subscription, meters[subscription].get()['count'])
        return metrics
    print(generateMetrics())
    return Response(generateMetrics(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

My `sources/passport/main` file looks like this:

```
subscription_types = ["opportunity", "account", "lead"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ...

    for subscription in subscription_types():
```

I also ran `export FLASK_ENV=app/__init__.py` before running `flask app`

When I visit `/metrics` I get an error that looks like some kind of circular dependency error.

When I uncomment that import comment in my views, file, the error occurs.
Pulling out `subscription_types` into a variable and importing it seems to be causing the problem.

My stack trace:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/jwan/extract/app/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/Users/jwan//extract/app/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sources.passport.main import subscription_types
  File "/Users/jwan/extract/sources/passport/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sources.passport.listener import subscribe, close_subscriptions
  File "/Users/jwan/extract/sources/passport/listener.py", line 18, in <module>
    QUEUE = boto3.resource("sqs").get_queue_by_name(QueueName=CONFIG["assertions_queue"][ENV])

botocore.errorfactory.QueueDoesNotExist: An error occurred (AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue) when calling the GetQueueUrl operation: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl versio
```

My `sources/passport/listener` file has this on line 18:

```
import gzip
import log
from os import getenv
from sources.passport.normalizer import normalize_message
from sources.app_metrics import meters

QUEUE = boto3.resource("sqs").get_queue_by_name(QueueName=CONFIG["assertions_queue"][ENV])
```

Comment: what is in your `sources.passport.listener` and `sources.passport.main` ?

Comment: edited my post...

Comment: you're probably misleading the name, what is `CONFIG["assertions_queue"][ENV]`?

Comment: But why would the problem go away when I comment out the import?